# Jenkins git-client: how to move to jgit on windows

Tags: git, jenkins, jgit

Since the Jenkins `git-client` plugin moved to use `jgit`, there have been a lot of issues with configuration and all of the solutions I have seen involve just switching back to using the old git command line since most installations by now have most of the hacks in place to make it work most of the time.

We are in the same boat, but the git command line is still *very* unreliable under Windows.  We like the idea of using `jgit` under the hood in the new `git-client`, and would like to see if it actually makes things better.  But I cannot find a single ounce of documentation on how to move to `jgit`.

FYI I already know about 

`-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.useCLI=false`

and

`-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.useJGit=true`

What I'm looking for is how to configure jgit for ssh, email/user info, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pending a better documentation (more complete than the [user guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide), and [forums](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/documentation/)), I would rely on:

[`org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/tree/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit):

You will find *tons* of tests, illustrating how JGit is supposed to be used.

- Email, for instance, is read from the config file in [`tst.org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ConfigTest`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/ConfigTest.java#L135-L206):

  ```
  authorName = localConfig.get(UserConfig.KEY).getAuthorName();
  authorEmail = localConfig.get(UserConfig.KEY).getAuthorEmail();
  ```
- SSH, as another example, [reads its config file](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/OpenSshConfigTest.java#L78-L79) as illustrated in [`tst.org.eclipse.jgit.transport.OpenSshConfigTest`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/OpenSshConfigTest.java#L78-L79)

  ```
  config("Host orcz\n" + "\tHostName repo.or.cz\n" + "\tPort 2222\n"
    + "\tUser jex\n" + "\tIdentityFile .ssh/id_jex\n"
    + "\tForwardX11 no\n");
  final Host h = osc.lookup("orcz");
  ```

And so on...

---

You also have the recent (August 2013) **[JGit cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook)**, created by [centic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411846/centic) ([Dominik Stadler](https://github.com/centic9))

#### Grab it

```
git clone git://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook
```

#### Build it and create Eclipse project files

```
mvn dependency:sources eclipse:eclipse package
```

#### Run it

> Import the project into an Eclipse workspace and execute the snippets there.

This cookbook has been [updated to JGit 3.0.3](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/commit/97be4ab881639c81deda4cbc07baf0a47903eb4b).

Answer (score 2):

JGit picks up some setting from the system wide configuration file `/etc/gitconfig` which git installs, but only if it can find it. It will find the file if git is in PATH, but you can also set the system property `jgit.gitprefix` to the path of where git is installed, i.e. path to the directory *above* the bin directory, .e. `C:\Program Files\Git`