# Commit with specific date using JGit Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, jgit

I have investigated the possibilities to control Git from Java.
What I have found is :

- Using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git command")` - to have Java execute commands with git
- Using JavaGit API (http://javagit.sourceforge.net/)
  or
  -Using Eclipse JGit API (http://www.jgit.org/)

I tried to write my own Java-wrapper for git with Runtime and ProcessBuilder, but I got problems with the process threads, was waiting for ever for the threads to finish some times.

I then looked into other solutions with APIs. First I tried JavaGit API, but I can't get that to work at all.

Second I tested JGit API, and it is looking great. But I soon find out that I could not set the commit date as I did with my Java-wrapper :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("git", "commit", "--date=" + "\"" + customDateString + "\"", "-m \"" + comment + "\"");
```

I downloaded the JGit source-code to see if I could implement it, but it was too much to read in and I could not find any issue tracker on Github for JGit to make a suggestion.

Can someone here help me do this?
Or tell me where I can write to make a suggestion to the developers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy, as you mention, first download [jgit](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit):

```
C:\> cd C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git> git clone https://github.com/eclipse/jgit
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git> cd jgit
```

Then search for a test ('`tst`') which involves "`authordate`":

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\jgit>grep -nRHIi authordate *|grep tst

org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CommitCommandTest.java:446:              final Date authorDate = new Date(1349621117000L);
```

That means you can have a look at the [org.eclipse.jgit.test.tst.org.eclipse/jgit/api.CommitCommandTest](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/8e356fc45e2b169572088ebdfb931ca788a5e220/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CommitCommandTest.java#L509-L529), function `commitAmendWithoutAuthorShouldSetOriginalAuthorAndAuthorTime()`:

You will see how to specify an author **and an author date**:

```java
final Date authorDate = new Date(1349621117000L);
PersonIdent firstAuthor = new PersonIdent(authorName, authorEmail,
   authorDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
git.commit().setMessage("initial commit").setAuthor(firstAuthor).call();
```

Note, [as I mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19004698/6309), the test classes are a good source of documentation/illustration for JGit.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking in the wrong place, for me it was logic to find some thing like git.commit().setDate("..."). Your method works, but I also used : git.commit().setCommitter(firstAuthor), before calling the "call()-method" to also change the commit date.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem some time ago and because JavaGit project seemed a bit dead just forked it, solved some bugs and made some bits going back to work.

You can try it at [the Swiss Army Java Git page](http://bit-man.github.io/SwissArmyJavaGit/) and also will be glad to help you.