# How to use java git for java project

Tags: java, git, egit, jgit

What I want to know is, there are many java implementation for access git.

1. Is there a way to use thees libraries? 
   I have seen so many tutorials saying how access git via java code. Its a single class that has git functions. But there is no consideration  how we use thees code for real application.
2. Then without using plug in IDEs(jgit,egit....)  or CLI tool how we use thees libraries for our java project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one library that you can use outside of any IDE, and for any of your java project, is [**JGit**](http://www.jgit.org/) ([sources at GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit), [User Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide)).

See "[Confusion in choosing between JavaGit, JGit and EGit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5335941/6309)"

That library can be used independently of Eclipse.

As [I mention in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19004698/6309), the package [`org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/tree/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit) includes tons of tests, for you to take example of.
This [JGit cookbook project](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) is also a good source of examples.

Comment: yep i got it, That examples gave me a clear idea. thank you cheers!